# Android ContentProvider/SQLiteDatabase query COUNT(*)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, count, android-contentprovider

I want to check if my table is empty:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI, "account");
Cursor countCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {"COUNT(*) AS COUNT_TABLE"}, null, null, null);
```

Here is my content provider query:

```
public synchronized Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    switch (uriType) {
    case ACCOUNT:
        checkColumns(projection, ACCOUNT);
        cursor = database.query(TableAccount.TABLE_ACCOUNT, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        break;
    case INPUT:
        checkColumns(projection, INPUT);
        cursor = database.query(TableInput.TABLE_INPUT, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        break;
    case OUTPUT:
        checkColumns(projection, OUTPUT);
        cursor = database.query(TableOutput.TABLE_OUTPUT, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

But every time I get this error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Unkonwn columns in projection

I prefer not to use a rawQuerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this method for getting the count of your sqlite database. I also added some where clause sample for your reference. feel free to modify it:

```
    public int getCount(String param1, String param2){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        long count;
        count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "TABLE_NAME",
                "param1=? AND param2=?", new String[]{param1, param2});

        db.close();
        return count;
    }
```